# Render HTML only if not in a given route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can I make sure the `.who` class only appears if we are not in the Life route?

```js
class App extends Component {
  render() {    
    return (
      <div className="App">

        <div className="centered-wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
            <Route path="/life" component={Life} />
            <Route path="*" component={Welcome}/>
          </Switch>

        </div>                
        <div className="who">[ <Link to="/life">Who's Marco</Link> ]</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: just the class or `div` element with the class?

Comment: that `div` element

Answer (score 0):

To write a condition based on route, you need to have route data in your App component. So you need to wrap your App component with [`withRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter) higher order component before export it.

```
export default withRouter(App);
```

Now you will get some router related properties as props of the App component. You can use `this.props.location.pathname` property which gives the current browser path to write your condition in JSX as follows.

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="centered-wrapper">
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Welcome} />
            <Route path="/life" component={Life} />
            <Route path="*" component={Welcome} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
        { (this.props.location.pathname !== "/life") && (<div className="who">[ <Link to="/life">Who's Marco</Link> ]</div>)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```